Should reply links for comments contain the nofollow tag? Or better dofollow?
I did analysis in semrush.com and spotted the issue:
1 outgoing internal link contains a nofollow attribute
This page:
https://porat.dev/%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/ has self referencing link with no follow attribute.
Here is the code chapter:
<div class="wp-block-comment-reply-link has-small-font-size"><a rel="nofollow" class="dp-ext dp-comment-reply-link" href="#comment-15" data-commentid="15" data-postid="5967" data-belowelement="comment-15" data-respondelement="respond" data-replyto="להגיב לדניאל" aria-label="להגיב לדניאל" hreflang="he-il">הגב</a></div></div>
-- The link is on this text: #comment-15
Is it ok or better to remove the nofollow tag?
I would like to figure out how it can impact for Google and do I need to fix it or not. Thanks.

This sounds like a webmasters.stackexchange.com kind of question

The "nofollow" attribute on this internal comment reply link is actually good practice. Here's why:
It's common for comment links to use "nofollow" to discourage spam.
This link isn't crucial for site navigation or passing PageRank.
It doesn't significantly impact your site's SEO or internal link structure.
You don't need to remove the "nofollow" attribute. Google understands this practice for comment links and it won't negatively affect your site. In fact, it shows you're following best practices for user-generated content.
If you're very concerned, you could remove it, but it's generally unnecessary and not recommended for comment links. The current implementation is appropriate from an SEO perspective.
